# Exporting a gdoc to html then importing it back as html into Gdoc doesn't preserve the original gdoc element

Tags: google-docs-api

So in my original gdoc I have a document with the following items:

```
Testing &amp;
```

So exporting as html this gives me the right html output. Like the following:

```
...html stuff here...
Testing &amp;amp;
...html stuff here...
```

However, when I try to import this back as a gdoc. I loose info. When I open it in gdoc I see the following:

```
 &
```

I lost the `amp;`

Here is how I'm importing back

```
 drive.files.create(
    {
        resource:{
             name,
             parents: [gdriveId],
             mimeType: 'text/html',
        },
        fields: "id",
        media: {
            mimeType: 'text/html',
            body: fs.createReadStream('./test.html')
        },
    },
```

Why I'm I loosing characters when i import html and open in Gdoc?

Comment: Have you tried to specify the mimeType to `application/vnd.google-apps.document` since what you would want to create is a Google Document?

Comment: Yea I tried. It's the same. It's looking like a bug in gdoc conversion

Comment: Hmm I see, if that's the case, you can file a bug [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=555502&template=1211163)